# mod_rewrite not properly redirecting Perl CGI urls

Tags: perl, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi

I have some files in my cgi-bin folder and other files in my html folder.

When I visit /cgi-bin/index.cgi the normal index page shows up. However, when I visit just my domain, like "domain.com" it gives me an apache page. Likely saying that there is no index.html page there, and there isn't a index.html page in my html folder. However, the .htaccess file in my html folder is suppose to redirect links properly. However, these links are not being redirected.

Here is the .htaccess file I have

```
deny from 127.1.1.4
deny from 127.1.1.1

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_CGI_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/?.+|$)$        ?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)   ?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 [L]

RewriteRule    ^embed-([0-9A-Za-z]{12})\.html$      ?op=video_embed&file_code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^embedmp3-([0-9A-Za-z]{12})\.html$   ?op=mp3_embed&file_code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^box$                    /cgi-bin/index_box.cgi [L]

RewriteRule    ^$                   /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
RewriteRule    ^free([0-9]+)\.html$         /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=registration&aff_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^checkfiles\.html$           /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=checkfiles [L]
RewriteRule    ^contact\.html$              /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=contact [L]
RewriteRule    ^premium\.html$              /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=payments [L]
RewriteRule    ^login\.html$                ?op=login [L]
RewriteRule    ^catalogue(.*)\.html$            /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=catalogue&date=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^news([0-9]*)\.html$         ?op=news&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^n([0-9]+)-.*\.html$         /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=news_details&news_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^faq\.html$              /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=faq [L]
RewriteRule    ^tos\.html$              /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=tos [L]
RewriteRule    ^links\.html$                /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=links [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^pages/([a-z0-9\-\_]+).html      /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=$1$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^users/([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})/?([0-9]+|$)    /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=user_public&usr_login=$1&fld_id=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule    \.pm$                    /404.html [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

For example this link: domain.com/?op=registration  does not redirect to the proper page.

Same as this link: domain.com/login.html

And every other link to be honest. I am 99% sure it's because of the .htaccess file posted above, but I can't seem to figure out the issue with the index redirect.

Comment: One thing you can do, to help with debugging, is to change all of these redirects to `[L,R=302]`.  Then `curl` the links to see if you get the (normally hidden by your browser) redirect links, incl. `<p>The document has moved <a href="...">here</a>.</p>`

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your rewrite rules are missing the /, e.g.:</s>

```
RewriteRule    ^/premium\.html$              /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=payments [L]
```

Update: even the home page redirect needs a /.

Start by scrapping everything you have and get a simple version working:

```
deny from 127.1.1.4
deny from 127.1.1.1

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule    ^$                    /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
```

Assuming that works, add the conditions and other rules one by one till you see what is breaking it.

Comment: Still not working.

I updated the .htaccess file by adding a couple of "/" in front, but that didn't fix it.

http://pastebin.com/36Wv92Ju
^ Link to new .htaccess

You can view the site here: http://50.7.6.116

Index page: http://50.7.6.116/cgi-bin/index.cgi 

The .htaccess doesn't redirect the home page to the index page as well.

Comment: Removed everything, and replaced it with what you updated the answer with. However, the homepage still doesn't redirect to /cgi-bin/index.cgi/

Comment: hmm; if you set deny from your-ip, does it deny you?

Comment: "In .htaccess files RewriteRule patterns don't start with a /:" 
Read this on another site..

Comment: ah, sorry; did removing it help?

Comment: No lol x.x. Seems to be something else that's causing this error.

Comment: Try adding Options +FollowSymLinks.